# How do I write a print job image to disk?

Tags: c#, printing, virtual-printer

When I print any document with my computer I want the printed page to be saved on my computer as for example a bmp or jpg file and printed to a piece of paper at the same time. I don't know if it is possible to extract this information from a printer or if it is possible to make a virtual printer and use it as "pass through" and get the image from the virtual printer and send it to the real printer afterwards.

OS: Windows XP.

Comment: You don't specify what OS, but all Windows printers can be pointed at a 'file' port, so that the generated raw binary printer commands get written to a file instead of to a real printer.

Comment: Sorry about that, this is windows xp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Win2PDF](http://www.win2pdf.com) virtual printer can create a PDF and print it to a paper printer at the same time.  To do this, set your real printer as the Windows default printer, print to the Win2PDF printer, and select the "[print file](http://www.win2pdf.com/doc/print-pdf.htm)" option in the file save window.  After the PDF file is created, it is automatically printed to your real printer.